# Could not determine the keys on any

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an interface of TestAll as show bellow that takes either Test1 or Test2 to Test13 but when I add Test 13, it throws an error of Could not determine the keys on any. Looks like if I have more than 12(Tests) then it throws an error. Is there a specific size it supposed to take?
This error is caused by this declaration `export interface Test {  test: TestAll['type']; id: string}`

`type TestAll = Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | ...`

`interface Test1 {`
type: 'Test1';
data: any;
`}`

`interface Test2 {`
`type: 'Test2';`
`data: any;`
`}`

`interface Test3 {`
`type: 'Test3';`
`data: any;`
`}`

Comment: You are assigning a type to a variable...

Comment: I have edited my question, it's actually a type not a variable.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gIzIN7JgCeADhAFzIDk6W2VA3MgCZxhyVwhFMC+AUKEixEKWmABM+QqQrVxExizYdkXHsgFDo8JGkxgAzNOJlKNA4aWt2nbn0Hgdo-VgAsJ2efFvrKuxpaTiJ64gCsnmbyBmF+tmr2mo7CumIGAGyRchZY6XGq6g7aIWlYAOxZ3gZl+QFFwamuYAAcldFYzbUJgcnOoQYAnG05YANdhUnFjeLYAAzDM7PjiUEpLjO4BKbZG8s9U+sG2FJbXu04ikw2BSu9JU3YxqdRI4979Wv9dB7PO0e+V383Q+fVKOAivyqdFigPiEwE-G2TQAggAbVHIAC8-GQuOQAB8Hji8YSFMTcaTLOSCU03NTKVgwvSmulmeIymyDM1OVgBjycLN+dhsEKJELDEK6XiaTMwgx+PwIAAPEgAeygYGQBy+mq2Bko4jRqIA2lRtlQALpMYDMShYKCgADmmiAA